# Improve Website Speed: Uploading files / Post Creation

Tags: wordpress, upload, amazon-web-services, pagespeed

To give you a little background, I have a website with WordPress as my content management system, which revolves around users uploading panoramic photos.  The site is hosted on a small Amazon EC2 instance.  After encountering a few days of noticeably slow speeds, I decided to address the issue.  In following the suggestions of several speed diagnostic sites (i.e., enabling browser caching, gzip compression, and keep-alive), I was able to increase my scores substantially and speed over basic site usage.  Unfortunately the site remains incredibly slow when uploading files as panoramic photos tend to be large in nature. When a user uploads a file, a new post is created with a resized version of the panoramic image, and once complete, the user is redirected to the new URL.  Does anyone have any suggestions to expedite this process?  Are there any options besides upgrading my server?

Comment: Perhaps some sort of client-side extension that does the resizing locally?  Like Flash or HTML5?

Comment: That sounds like an option.  I tried the Dynamic Image Resizer plugin suggested by Brasofilo, but had no luck.

Comment: What exactly a *"small Amazon EC2 instance"* offers? Do you have some kind of performance report?

Comment: M1 Small Instance - 1.7 GiB of memory,  1 EC2 Compute Unit (1 virtual core with 1 Ec2 Compute Unit), 160 GB of local instance storage, 32-bit or 64-bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin does exactly that:

> ### [Dynamic Image Resizer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/)
>
> Changes the way WordPress creates images to make it generate the images only when they are actually used somewhere, on the fly. Images created thusly will be saved in the normal upload directories, for later fast sending by the webserver. The result is that space is saved (since images are only created when needed), and uploading images is much faster (since it's not generating the images on upload anymore).

[The author](http://profiles.wordpress.org/Otto42/) is WordPress core developer and knows WP code inside out.

Comment: I have installed and activated the Dynamic Image Resizer plugin, but unfortunately it does not appear to have sped up the upload / post creation process.